# leetcode 66)Plus One .Array memory allocation and BigInteger problem

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management, return, biginteger

I'm a beginner java programmer and having a doubt in Array memory allocation and BigInteger in the question 66)Plus One of leetCode. The question statement is as such:

Q)You are given a large integer represented as an integer array digits, where each digits[i] is the ith digit of the integer. The digits are ordered from most significant to least significant in left-to-right order. The large integer does not contain any leading 0's.

Increment the large integer by one and return the resulting array of digits.

Example 1:

Input: digits = [1,2,3]
Output: [1,2,4]
Explanation: The array represents the integer 123.
Incrementing by one gives 123 + 1 = 124.
Thus, the result should be [1,2,4].
Example 2:

Input: digits = [4,3,2,1]
Output: [4,3,2,2]
Explanation: The array represents the integer 4321.
Incrementing by one gives 4321 + 1 = 4322.
Thus, the result should be [4,3,2,2].
Example 3:

Input: digits = [9]
Output: [1,0]
Explanation: The array represents the integer 9.
Incrementing by one gives 9 + 1 = 10.
Thus, the result should be [1,0].

Constraints:

1 <= digits.length <= 100
0 <= digits[i] <= 9
digits does not contain any leading 0's.

I used BigInteger to solve this question but the time required is showing 13-16 secs .My solution:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
class Solution 
{
    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) 
    {
       String s=ArrtoString(digits);
       BigInteger n=new BigInteger(s);
       BigInteger n1 = n.add(new BigInteger("1"));
       int c=n1.toString().length();
       int[] d=new int[c];
       String result=n1.toString();
       d=StringToArr(result);
       return d;
    }
    public String ArrtoString(int[] arr)
    {
       String s="";
       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
       {
           s=s+arr[i];
       }
       return s;
    }
    public int[] StringToArr(String s)
    {
       int[] arr= new int[s.length()];
       for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
       {
           arr[i]=s.charAt(i)-'0';
       }
       return arr;
    }
}
```

I found an alternative solution with time required 0-1 seconds .Solution is as such :

```
class Solution 
{
    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits)
    {
      boolean carry = true;
      for (int i = digits.length - 1; carry==true &&  i >= 0; i--) 
      {
        carry = digits[i] == 9;
        if(carry)
        {   
            digits[i] = 0 ;
        }
        else
        {
            digits[i] =digits[i] + 1;;
        }
      }

      if (carry) 
      {
        int[] tmp = new int[digits.length + 1];
        tmp[0] = 1;
        System.arraycopy(digits, 0, tmp, 1, digits.length);
        digits = tmp;
      }
    return digits;
   }
}
```

I have two doubts :

1)Why is the time required so high when BigInteger is used. Is there any way to optimize it?

2)In the second solution at the end it's written `digits = tmp`. What is the purpose of this statement? Is it copying all elements of tmp[] array to digits[] array? If so then how ? because size of tmp[] array is 1 greater than digits[] array and if I'm not wrong then array size once declared cannot be changed. Or am I wrong? Feel free to correct me. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The purpose of the ``digits = tmp`` is so you can ``return digits;`` at the end of the function. Some coders prefer having only one exit point (``return``) in a function for better readability. An alternative would be to just ``return tmp;`` instead.

Comment: Oh and it works because after digits will just be a reference to the tmp array. The original digit array will be unreferenced and cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Comment: As for 1) the reason it takes so long is because of all the ``new ..`` object creations and the multiple loops. You convert the array to a string thats one loop, then you initizalize the big integer, which also needs to loop over the string and does a bunch of checks if the string can even be represented by a number, then you create another BigInteger and use another loop to convert a string back to an int array. The other solutions only uses a single loop and in the event of a carry ``System.arraycopy`` which is very fast.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @SchokokuchenBäcker .I understood the explanation for question 1) but for the 2nd one 'digits = tmp' I could not understand .tmp and digits are arrays so how can you equal them just like normal primitive datatype variables? Can you explain this "after digits will just be a reference to the tmp array." part? Or share any resources from where I can learn about this referencing of Array ? Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Think of ``tmp`` as a pointer to an array with length x and ``digits`` as a pointer to another array of length y. Now with ``digits = tmp`` you say: I want ``digits`` to point to the array that ``tmp`` is pointing to. The original array ``digits`` was pointing to is now unreferenced, meaning nothing points to it and the garbage collector will free it from memory. This is ok because both arrays are of type ``int[]``. As you can see the type stays the same regardless of the length of the arrays.

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker thanks a lot .Had to revise how array and methods work in java to properly understand what you meant. Thanks a lot for pointing out and explaining .

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution {
    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        int len = digits.length;
        int[] result = new int[len + 1];
        if(len == 0){
            result[0] = 1;
            return result;
        }
        int carry = 0;
        result[len] = (digits[len - 1] + 1) % 10;
        carry = (digits[len - 1] + 1) / 10;
        for(int i = len - 2; i >= 0; i--){
            result[i + 1] = (digits[i] + carry ) % 10;
            carry = (digits[i] + carry ) / 10;
        }
        if(carry == 1){
            result[0] = 1;
            return result;
        }else{
            return Arrays.copyOfRange(result, 1, len + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).